# trouble using an ai generated matte for rotoscoping

Tags: compositing-nodes

My apologies if this is a dumb question. I made a python script to generate mattes using machine learning, following Damien Allen's tutorial (https://www.provideocoalition.com/automatic-rotoscopingfor-free/). Now I have an image sequence of my son waving a "lightsaber" around in my living room, and an image sequence of mattes that I want to use to remove the background. It seems like it should be a pretty straightforward compositing job, I just can't figure it out. It seems like all of the masking nodes in the compositing workspace are for generating masks, and I can't figure out how to use something that was generated outside of Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Go to compositing.
Check use nodes.
Use the set alpha node and two movie clip nodes.
Plug the movie into image and matte into alpha. Use an invert node if its inverted.
plug the result from the set alpha to your output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)